# Removing the unit "pm" from atomic positions

Tags: curated-data, units

The following input yields an output with the unit pm (0.01 Angstroms), how do you eliminate this unit so that only numbers are generated.

```
ChemicalData["OleicAcid", "AtomPositions"]
```

Comment: Use `QuantityMagnitude`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `QuantityMagnitude` is what you want:

```
QuantityMagnitude @ ChemicalData["OleicAcid", "AtomPositions"]
```